# can't start new thread in aws cli dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, aws-cli

I am trying to run a aws s3 cli command during docker build and it is giving me error `can't start new thread`. I tried setting `max_concurrent_requests` to `1` to limits threads to 1.

```
...
RUN yarn build
RUN aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 1
RUN aws sts get-caller-identity
RUN aws s3 rm s3://public-assets/build/_next/static --recursive
...
```

The last `s3 rm` command is giving the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles into this exact same issue, it is not a AWS CLI specific issue in anyway. I was using `alpine` image and then I switched to `ubuntu`. Once, I switched to `ubuntu` base image, everything worked out the way it is intended to.